# How to parameterize database name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, concatenation, declare

I have the list of servers and databases, trying to use OLTP and WH database in the same script as below.

```
DECLARE @oltp VARCHAR(50)
SET @oltp = 'Employee'

DECLARE @wh VARCHAR(25)
SET @wh = @oltp + '_wh'
   
SELECT * 
FROM Employee_wh..employee_sales_item --working

SELECT * 
FROM @wh..employee_sales_item --not working
```

I'm getting the following exception

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 86
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Please help me to fix `@wh..employee_sales_item` using the declared variable.

Comment: A database isn't a value, so it can't be passes as a parameter value. What are you trying to do? There are almost certainly better ways to do it. Perhaps you need to switch to the other database first. Or you can create SYNONYMs for the other tables in the database you're already in.

Comment: If you want to do this, it normally denotes a design flaw, if I am honest. The database name, in your queries, should be static. If it's the application that needs to connect to the right database, then it should be defining the right database in the connection string *not* the query string.

Comment: A SQL query is like a function in a strongly typed language. Parameters are the same as function parameters - a way to pass values.  The tables, indexes *and* statistics are like the types. The database server will compile the SQL query into very different execution plans based on the actual fields, types, indexes and value statistics, and reuse it each time with different parameter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @oltp VARCHAR(50)
SET @oltp = 'Employee';

DECLARE @wh VARCHAR(25)
SET @wh =  '_wh';

DECLARE @DatabaseName SYSNAME = @oltp + @wh;
   
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = @DatabaseName)
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @ErrorMsg VARCHAR(1000);
      SET @ErrorMsg = QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName)  + ' database does not exist';
      RAISERROR(@ErrorMsg , 16 , 2); 
    END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM '  
                               + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) 
                               + N'..employee_sales_item;';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to exchange any element of schema (column, table, schema, database) with a parameter you need to use 'dynamic SQL'.

In your case it would be something like below:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(400),
        @db nvarchar(30)

set @db = N'Employee_wh'
set @sql = N'select  * from '+@db+N'..employee_sales_item'

exec sp_executesql  @sql
```